# How do I create a thread dump via JMX?

Tags: java, jconsole, jstack

I have a Tomcat running as a Windows Service, and those are known not to work well with jstack. jconsole is working well, on the other hand, and I can see stacks of individual threads (I'm connecting to "localhost:port" to access it).

How can I use jconsole or a similar tool to dump all the thread stacks into a file? (similar to jstack)

Answer (score 6):

You can use the [ThreadMXBean](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/management/ThreadMXBean.html) management interface.

This [FullThreadDump](http://www.java2s.com/Code/Java/Development-Class/ThisFullThreadDumpclassdemonstratesthecapabilitytogetafullthreaddumpandalsodetectdeadlockremotely.htm) class demonstrates the capability to get a full thread dump and also detect deadlock remotely using JMX.

Answer (score 6):

Nowadays you can use jvisualvm tool to connect to your remote JVM through JMX and create a thread dump. Don't know if this was available

[image: Java VisualVM]

Comment: It's incredibly slow :(

Answer (score 3):

Here's another code sample that will write a stack dump to a file:

> http://pastebin.com/zwcKC0hz

We use this over JMX to give us an approximation of the stack dump you get when you make a JMX request or if the process detects high, unexpected load.

Answer (score 1):

It would be helpful if you take a flight recording to get a deeper view on the JVM behavior, specially focusing on the Hot Methods.

Usually, a recording of half an hour is enough. To trigger a recording, you must be logged in to the machines, and issue the following command:

If using Java HotSpot 1.8.x:

$JAVA_HOME/bin/jcmd VM.unlock_commercial_features 
$JAVA_HOME/bin/jcmd  JFR.start duration=1800s settings=profile filename=/tmp/recording.jfr

IF using java HotSpot 1.7.x:

Edit your $HOME/conf/wrapper.conf file by adding the following parameters on JVM startup:

wrapper.java.additiona.=-XX:+UnlockCommercialFeatures 
wrapper.java.additional.=-XX:+FlightRecorder

(replace  with the corresponding positional number )

Then, have your instances restarted. Once done, issue the following command :

$JAVA_HOME/bin/jcmd  JFR.start duration=1800s settings=profile filename=/tmp/recording.jfr

The flight recording wil produce a file on /tmp/recording.jfr upon termination.