# How to see what monitor is a thread waiting for via API?

Tags: java, multithreading, junit, monitor

We have a junit test runner which timeout if one test is hanging. Now I want create a thread dump via API.

I know I can request the stacktraces via Thread.getAllStackTraces(). But the thread dump on the console include many more information like the monitor which a thread is waiting.

Are there an API to request the monitor on which a thread is waiting?

Comment: It's unclear to me - do you want to do it programmatically or manually?

Comment: if you generate all the stack traces won't you see where a thread is waiting?

Comment: I think API is clear. I want do it programmatically. I want write the dump in the logs from test server if a timeout occur. The test server should not freeze that it terminate. That manually is not possible.

Comment: that's fine. Definitely API = programmatically. I just wasn't sure if we are on the same page.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use JMX to create a thread dump.

See [How do I create a thread dump via JMX?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3958938/how-do-i-create-a-thread-dump-via-jmx) for an example. The [ThreadInfo](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/management/ThreadInfo.html) class supports getting the locked monitors.

Answer (score 1):

JDK 6 documentation contains a section on programmatic monitoring of the JVM MBeans .
I have never used them and would not be able to provide you sample code but it will definately give you a start.

[Managing and monitoring programmatic way](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/technotes/guides/management/agent.html#gdfci)

[The Attach API to connect to a remote JVM](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/technotes/guides/attach/index.html)

I hope it helps , It will be very helpful if you can share the outcome of your research.